# Magento Product Export Creates "undefined offset" error in Product.php line 1766

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

When I try to export my products to a CSV, I get a 500 Internal Server error. The system log tells me:

> ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset:  1766  in
>   /chroot/home/mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php
>   on line 657

Any idea what might be causing this error? All advice is appreciated. I am running Magento 1.5.1

Comment: Can you post code from line 657 from Product.php?